# Change background color on button click?

Tags: android

I want the background color of my second activity to change once a button is pressed. This is my_activity2.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity2"
android:background="#ffdb4b5e">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/thing1"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    />
```

This is my MyActivity2.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);

 final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.things_array);
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random RAND=new Random();
        String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];
        tv.setText(nextValue);
```

I have the background colors stored in the strings.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="colorcode_array">
    <item>3498db</item>
    <item>2ecc71</item>
    <item>9b59b6</item>
    <item>f1c40f</item>
    <item>1abc9c</item>
    <item>2980b9</item>
    <item>8e44ad</item>
    <item>e41c1c</item>
    <item>2ecca9</item>
    <item>752ecc</item>
    <item>4f2ecc</item>
    <item>2eccc3</item>
    <item>2ecc53</item>
    <item>2ecc2e</item>
    <item>5bcc2e</item>
    <item>9ecc2e</item>
    <item>cca12e</item>
    <item>cc712e</item>
    <item>f1c209</item>
    <item>86f109</item>
    <item>f11616</item>
    <item>9c1818</item>
</string-array>
```

Now how can I make the background color change on random when the button "Next" is clicked? Matthew

EDIT:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);
    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);

    final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.things_array);
    final String[] value = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorcode_array);
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random RAND=new Random();
        String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];
        String newValue = value[index++];
        tv.setText(nextValue);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(newValue));
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your array is in wrong format since you are using `hex` it should have hashtag before the hex color so you can parse it later in the code.

**sample:**

change all your colors to this format

```
<string-array name="colorcode_array">
<item>#3498db</item>
<item>#2ecc71</item>
<item>#9b59b6</item>
<item>#f1c40f</item>
<item>#1abc9c</item>
   .
   .
```

In your layout you need to have a reference id in your `RelativeLayout` so you need to add an **id** on it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/my_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity2"
android:background="#ffdb4b5e">
```

Then reference it in your `onCreate` same as what you did in your `Button`.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);
```

Now to change the color of the background of your `RelativeLayout` you now need to parse it using the `Color.parseColor` and set the Background of the reference to the `RelativeLayout` that you create as stated above.

**sample:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Random RAND=new Random();
    String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
}
```

EDIT:

create Global instance of int

```
int index = 0;
```

in your onClick increment it

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String nextValue = values[index++];
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
}
```

Edit #2:

```
int index = 0;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Comment: Works perfectyly, but one more thing. How can i make it unrandom? So just in order?

Comment: @user3456590 use an `int = 0` to use in index and increment it when button is clicked.

Comment: +1'ed, How exactly do i do that? I've only started a few days ago

Comment: @user3456590 see EDIT above

Comment: It changes to the very first color in the array, but then doesnt change anymore

Comment: @user3456590 is the `index ` a global instance?

Comment: @user3456590 post the entire class above and Ill show you.

Comment: @user3456590 typo?? change this `tv.setText(nextValue);` to `tv.setText(newValue);`

Comment: No i did that on purpose, because tv is textview and loads the text from things_array

Comment: @user3456590 post the entire class not the onCreate

Comment: The code doesn't go well with Stackoverflow code viewer.. http://gyazo.com/969b2c794dd1a637527b36b1e2936816

Comment: You got a solution for me?

Comment: @user3456590 see the EDIT 2

Comment: Hmm.. still randomn, and at the 4th button click the app crashes?

Comment: Im sorry to bother you so much btw

Comment: @user3456590 well you can post another question. for this. :)). I given you all the alternative but seems it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Random RAND=new Random();
    String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Set another String array pointing to R.array.colorcode_array and do as Spurdow's answer tells you to. Alternatively, set an id to your root `RelativeLayout` and use setBackgroundColor() on that `RelativeLayout`,on your code.

Comment: Do I just add that to my existing onclick method?