# Change layout background color on button click

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, background-color

I'm getting an error  when trying to set the background color of a layout I get a nullpointerexception and I don't know why. I've looked at various posts (like this [Change background color on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332676/change-background-color-on-button-click)) and my code seems correct, but still the layout doesn't seem be called.
This is my activity's code

```
public class Color extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.color);

    findViewById(R.id.blue).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.red).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.pink).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.green).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.yellow).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.light_blue).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_blue).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_red).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_pink).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_greend).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_yellow).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_light_blue).setOnClickListener(this);


}
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.blue:

        LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_call);
        l1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
```

and this is the logcat error

```
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837): Process: com.example.primeirocasopratico, PID: 4837
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at com.example.primeirocasopratico.Color.onClick(Color.java:42)

01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5327)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
01-30 01:25:06.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have also tried to set the background this way:

```
findViewById(R.layout.city).setBackgroundColor( android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
```

and a few other variations and nothing seems to work...

**(EDIT 2)** I seem to have found the problem. It seems to be related with me trying to edit layouts associated with other activities. Any Idea how to solve that?

Comment: Which line is line 42?

Comment: @AlexK`l1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);`

Comment: Yup. Then see my answer below, it's correct.

Comment: Where is your layout_call LinearLayout present?

Comment: @Dhina it's in another activity called `call.java`

Comment: Have you tried: l1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)); ??

Comment: @herbertD yes, I've tried every way possible. The problem is that i'm calling objects not associated with the activity....

Comment: @Rasmnev I've posted a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared preferences could be your solution. Oncreate of every activity check for the variable and set the color.

```
public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.blue:
            backgroundColor("blue");
            break;
 }
}


private void backgroundColor(String color) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("BackgroundColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.clear();
          editor.putString("Color", color);
          editor.commit();
    }
```

In other Activities

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("BackgroundColor",
                  MODE_PRIVATE); 
String bgcolor = prefs.getString("Color","Anydefaultcolor");
```

now you can set your layout to bgcolor

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give us quite enough information to give you a complete answer, but if what you gave us is the complete code, then your error is in here:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.blue:

        LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_call);
        l1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
```

Specifically, those last two lines. Make sure that your `LinearLayout` is, in fact, called `layout_call`. The `NullPointerException` means that you probably either made a type in the name, or simply didn't give it a name.

EDIT: Now that you made it clear which line is the error, I can confirm that this is the error. `R.id.layout_call` doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
public class Color extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 

private LinearLayout linLay;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.color);

    linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_call);

    findViewById(R.id.blue).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.red).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.pink).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.green).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.yellow).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.light_blue).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_blue).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_red).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_pink).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_greend).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_yellow).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_light_blue).setOnClickListener(this);


}
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.blue:

        linLay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
```

Comment: I supposed the error was there, because the app only stops when I click and the `NullPointerException` probably means l1 is a null. The id is corrected. I didn't gave it one at first but after going through a few post I added an Id to all the layouts I want to change the background (I have 9) and I've tried with all of them and I always get the same error. Whatelse do you need me to provide?

Comment: @Rasmnev try what I've just added

Comment: I've tried that way already...same error
I even did a clean/ rebuild and tried again and nothing...

Comment: I added the layout with the buttons, maybe there's an error there because I can't even change the color of textViews...

Comment: I'm reading a few fundamentals and I found that the `setBackgroundColor` receiver an `int` as argument. May that be the problem?

Comment: And the id is not layout_call in the xml it is layout_color. I think the OP means to have some other layout.. Setting BG to the relative layout works fine with no edit.

Comment: @Dhina No the id is layout_call because I'm trying to change the color of layouts not associated with my activity and that seems to be the problem

Comment: use sharedpreferences may be. save the color in a variable. access in other activity and set the color or try inflating the layout and set the color

Comment: that probably isn't a very good solution because I have to change the color of 9 layouts at the same time....

Comment: @AlexK the layout  `layout_call` is a linear layout, it's a layout associated with another activity.  The layout I had there was the layout associated with the activity.

Comment: @Rasmnev shared preferences should be your solution IMO. Oncreate of every activity check for the variable and set the color. It will do good more than harm

Comment: @Dhina it worked great. please post your answer so I can market as correct

Comment: @Dhina I found only a small problem, when I start the app it doesn't save the changes I make. Is there a way for me to make them permanent?

Comment: Now it's permanent. I just applied the sharedPreferences to all the layouts and it is saving my customizations. Thanks a lot I don't think I would ever have thought of that. Your answer is perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change another Activity's UI, send a message to it by Broadcast or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Like this

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventUpdateUI());
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I never used EventBus, or broadcast... can you show me how to change, for example, the activity `call.java`'s layout color that has the layout with ID `layout_call` associtated?